# Streaming file without downloading it

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

If I have a large image for example (50MB+), and I want to load it into a Node.js page from an external URL, how can I render the page and stream the file to the client, without saving it to the server or having to wait for it to fully download before displaying the page?

All examples I've found so far rely on something like:

```
request('http://google.com/doodle.png').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('doodle.png'))
```

This requires the file to be saved before it can be outputted. How can I simply stream it rather than download it?

Answer (score 1):

The `res` object you get from express is an [`http.ServerResponse`](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_writable) object, meaning you can stream directly to it:

```
request('http://google.com/doodle.png').pipe(res);
```

Comment: Thanks. I have another problem, which is that I'd like to stream it to the user while also saving it to the server. So what I need to do is pipe it to the server, and then pipe that to the user. Is that possible?